# How I can set the index of Datagridview to 0

Tags: vb.net

How I can set the index of DataGridView to 0?

I developed a pharmacy software where I want to add values from TextBoxes into DataGridView with adding a new row. It is working but the problem is when I clear the value of DataGridView by using this code

```
dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows.Clear()
```

then when I try the previous procedure it show this error in VB.NET

> Index was out of range, Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:index

**Code:**

```
Dim rowcounter As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows.Add()

    dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows(rowcounter).Cells("ColumnBarcodeNo").Value = txtBarcodeNo.Text
    dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows(rowcounter).Cells("ColumnName").Value = dgvSale.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
    dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows(rowcounter).Cells("ColumnQuantity").Value = txtQuantity.Text
    dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows(rowcounter).Cells("ColumnSalePrice").Value = txtSalePrice.Text
    dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows(rowcounter).Cells("ColumnAmount").Value = txtTotalAmount.Text
    dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows(rowcounter).Cells("ColumnReject").Value = "Reject"
    dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows(rowcounter).Cells("ColumnStockID").Value = dgvSale.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
    dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows(rowcounter).Cells("ColumnStockQuantity").Value = dgvSale.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value

    System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(rowcounter), rowcounter - 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: You can add Row like this instead dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows.Add(txtBarcodeNo.Text,dgvSale.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value,txtQuantity.Text...and so on) no need to add row then fill cells individualy, do dgvSoldMedicineInfo(y,x).value=something only when you need to edit that individual cell. And why do you need the row counter variable? You can get the count of rows directly with dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows.Count

Answer (score 0):

There's really no point to that `rowcounter` variable in that context and it's bad form to keep using `dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows(rowcounter)` over and over again.  The proper way to do that would be like so:

```
Dim rowIndex = dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows.Add()
Dim row = dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows(rowIndex)
Dim cells = row.Cells

cells("ColumnBarcodeNo").Value = txtBarcodeNo.Text
cells("ColumnName").Value = dgvSale.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
'etc.
```

That said, why do that when the `Add` method is overloaded and will accept all the cell values up front?

```
dgvSoldMedicineInfo.Rows.Add(txtBarcodeNo.Text,
                             dgvSale.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value,
                             ...)
```